# Can someone spot the error with this array?

Tags: php, arrays

I am populating an array with variables from a table.

For some reason, it doesn't like the indexes 08 or 09.

When I have

```
$numCorrectArray = array(01=>$q01TotalCorrect, 02=>$q02TotalCorrect, 03=>$q03TotalCorrect, 04=>$q04TotalCorrect, 05=>$q05TotalCorrect, 06=>$q06TotalCorrect, 07=>$q07TotalCorrect, 08=>$q08TotalCorrect, 09=>$q09TotalCorrect, 10=>$q10TotalCorrect, 11=>$q11TotalCorrect, 12=>$q12TotalCorrect, 13=>$q13TotalCorrect, 14=>$q14TotalCorrect, 15=>$q15TotalCorrect, 16=>$q16TotalCorrect, 17=>$q17TotalCorrect, 18=>$q18TotalCorrect, 19=>$q19TotalCorrect, 20=>$q20TotalCorrect, 21=>$q21TotalCorrect, 22=>$q22TotalCorrect, 23=>$q23TotalCorrect, 24=>$q24TotalCorrect, 25=>$q25TotalCorrect, 26=>$q26TotalCorrect, 27=>$q27TotalCorrect, 28=>$q28TotalCorrect, 29=>$q29TotalCorrect, 30=>$q30TotalCorrect, 31=>$q31TotalCorrect, 32=>$q32TotalCorrect, 33=>$q33TotalCorrect, 34=>$q34TotalCorrect, 35=>$q35TotalCorrect, 36=>$q36TotalCorrect, 37=>$q37TotalCorrect, 38=>$q38TotalCorrect, 39=>$q39TotalCorrect, 40=>$q40TotalCorrect);
```

print_r spits out

```
Array ( [1] => 60 [2] => 69 [3] => 38 [4] => 69 [5] => 70 [6] => 47 [7] => 39 [0] => 70 [10] => 56 [11] => 37 [12] => 32 [13] => 24 [14] => 48 [15] => 72 [16] => 65 [17] => 26 [18] => 50 [19] => 55 [20] => 36 [21] => 40 [22] => 49 [23] => 37 [24] => 33 [25] => 66 [26] => 64 [27] => 68 [28] => 54 [29] => 59 [30] => 25 [31] => 58 [32] => 58 [33] => 58 [34] => 48 [35] => 70 [36] => 51 [37] => 67 [38] => 54 [39] => 62 [40] => 45 )
```

Meanwhile, when I do

```
$numCorrectArray = array(01=>$q01TotalCorrect, 02=>$q02TotalCorrect, 03=>$q03TotalCorrect, 04=>$q04TotalCorrect, 05=>$q05TotalCorrect, 06=>$q06TotalCorrect, 07=>$q07TotalCorrect, 88=>$q08TotalCorrect, 99=>$q09TotalCorrect, 10=>$q10TotalCorrect, 11=>$q11TotalCorrect, 12=>$q12TotalCorrect, 13=>$q13TotalCorrect, 14=>$q14TotalCorrect, 15=>$q15TotalCorrect, 16=>$q16TotalCorrect, 17=>$q17TotalCorrect, 18=>$q18TotalCorrect, 19=>$q19TotalCorrect, 20=>$q20TotalCorrect, 21=>$q21TotalCorrect, 22=>$q22TotalCorrect, 23=>$q23TotalCorrect, 24=>$q24TotalCorrect, 25=>$q25TotalCorrect, 26=>$q26TotalCorrect, 27=>$q27TotalCorrect, 28=>$q28TotalCorrect, 29=>$q29TotalCorrect, 30=>$q30TotalCorrect, 31=>$q31TotalCorrect, 32=>$q32TotalCorrect, 33=>$q33TotalCorrect, 34=>$q34TotalCorrect, 35=>$q35TotalCorrect, 36=>$q36TotalCorrect, 37=>$q37TotalCorrect, 38=>$q38TotalCorrect, 39=>$q39TotalCorrect, 40=>$q40TotalCorrect);
```

print_r spits out

```
Array ( [1] => 60 [2] => 69 [3] => 38 [4] => 69 [5] => 70 [6] => 47 [7] => 39 [88] => 66 [99] => 70 [10] => 56 [11] => 37 [12] => 32 [13] => 24 [14] => 48 [15] => 72 [16] => 65 [17] => 26 [18] => 50 [19] => 55 [20] => 36 [21] => 40 [22] => 49 [23] => 37 [24] => 33 [25] => 66 [26] => 64 [27] => 68 [28] => 54 [29] => 59 [30] => 25 [31] => 58 [32] => 58 [33] => 58 [34] => 48 [35] => 70 [36] => 51 [37] => 67 [38] => 54 [39] => 62 [40] => 45 )
```

Notice how it handles keys 08 and 09 vs when I change them to 88 and 99 in the second example.

Can anyone spot what I am doing wrong?

Comment: maybe your php version will be helpfull

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Preppending a number with a 0 in PHP forces the number to be interpreted as an octal value. There is no 8 and 9 in octal notation.

Why not just use 1, 2, 3, etc? Or if you really need it to be two digits, use strings as key, i.e. '01', '02', '03'...

Comment: You don't need '0...' keys if zeros are required for output because you can format the key with sprintf.

Comment: @DavidBarker -- Kind of hard to do that when an error dialog says "You can accept an answer in 5 minutes." Intended to and have now accepted the best answer as early as system allows.

Comment: Just shows how fast I got a right answer (especially impressive for me considering it's 4 AM my time)!

Answer (score 2):

0... is octal numbers, there's no 08 or 09 so PHP treats them as 0.